# Understanding a DB schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

Using MySQL Workbench I reverse engineered phpbb's database to see what the schema would look like.

Well it came up with about 20 tables that were associated with each other through various relationships (no concern there). There are another 50 or so tables sitting independently though without any relationships.

My concern is not that this is a true representation of the database phpbb uses or not. It did bring up some questions that I couldn't find the answers for though (probably due to searching for the wrong terms)

Do databases actually exist and work like this? 
If so what are they called?

**EDIT**:  For everyone concentrating on the phpbb DB I don't understand why you are since I said that is not a concern.  I only referred to it because that is what I was looking at when I came up with these questions.

To try my questions in different words...

If a DB is to have an arbitrary number (say 1/3) of tables that are associated to one another through relationships and then the remaining 2/3's of the tables are independent (i.e. no relationship to other tables) is there a name for this?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the database and the schema. Some databases are legitimately built this way. Without _details_ it is impossible to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: details?  I am not asking you to explain the DB design of phpbb.

Comment: You are asking me to tell if you the vague description you provided is normal or not and what to call it. I can't do that with a vague description, I need details. It's one of my many failings.

Comment: Oded, with all your comments at me that I deleted we are not communicating on the same page as you are proud to point out. No worries that you can't help me out.  Thanks

Comment: @swisscheese huh? Maybe there are deleted comments I don't know about, but as from what I can see, Oded is right. `Some databases are legitimately built this way. Without details it is impossible to give you an accurate answer`... although this is something that probably only somebody familiar with phpBB can tell fully

Comment: What are you asking ? (Note that the phpbb developer might simply not have used foreign keys to describe the table relations, or they might have used MyISAM tables that does not provide foreign keys. Foreign keys is what a reverse engineering tool uses to figure out table relations)

Comment: @Pekka and nos please see my edit.

Comment: @nos, thanks for explaining how the reverse engineering tools work.  I originally had this in another question but Oded used that part of my question, among others, to make a point that his knowledge has far surpassed mine.  I am here asking questions in the first place to learn, not to help someone else feel better by giving them a chance put me down.  Thanks for taking the time to add valuable information that is useful and I can actually learn from.  I did edit my question to hopefully make it more clear what I am after.

Comment: @swisscheese.  If the tables have relations, but those relations are not defined as FK constraints, then by definition, it is not a Relational database.  Many people implement such monstrosities.  Similarly, many people implement data integrity rules "outside the database, in app code"; that too is not a database.  The name for it is Sub-Standard Data Store (using the RDBMS as merely a data store).  Calling it a "database" or "relational" is fraudulent.

Comment: @swisscheese @nos. *Foreign keys is what a reverse engineering tool uses to figure out table relations*. Depends on the tool.  The better ones (eg. ERwin) have an option to Infer Relations: that means it picks up matching column names and datatypes where FK constraints are absent.  Also, the ancient (1984 ?) SQL standard requirement is still valid: you can define "keys" and "foreign" by name, separate to the FK definition.  The cheaper tools pick up only the FK definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly easy to create a database/system without any linked tables...would I do it that way? No, but I have seen plenty.

I suspect that at least some of those 2/3 of those tables are in fact related (in the loose-est sense) to other tables, but that relationship is done through the code, not enforced through the database.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Is there a name that describes such a design?

Comment: Not a good name - I think it is more a lack of a complete design than a purposeful design decision.

Answer (score 2):

Having tables that aren't linked to others can be reasonable, but I'm not sure that's the case in the PHPBB database.

Check the link below for an attempt at documenting the PHPBB database structure.  It includes about 20 tables, which sounds like the linked tables you saw.  Can you provide the names of the unlinked tables you're looking at?

http://www.phpbbdoctor.com/doc_tables.php

Table list:

> phpbb_auth_access
>
> phpbb_banlist
>
> phpbb_categories
>
> phpbb_config
>
> phpbb_confirm
>
> phpbb_disallow
>
> phpbb_forums
>
> phpbb_forum_prune
>
> phpbb_groups
>
> phpbb_posts
>
> phpbb_posts_text
>
> phpbb_privmsgs
>
> phpbb_privmsgs_text
>
> phpbb_ranks
>
> phpbb_search_results
>
> phpbb_search_wordlist
>
> phpbb_search_wordmatch
>
> phpbb_sessions
>
> phpbb_smilies
>
> phpbb_themes
>
> phpbb_themes_name
>
> phpbb_topics
>
> phpbb_topics_watch
>
> phpbb_users
>
> phpbb_user_group
>
> phpbb_vote_desc
>
> phpbb_vote_results
>
> phpbb_vote_voters
>
> phpbb_words

EDIT - In answer to your question edit, there isn't a specific name for having 1/3 linked tables, and 2/3 unlinked.  The main scenario I can think of off the top of my head for unlinked tables is having audit tables tracking the changes that occur over time in particular tables.  There would be less audit 'unlinked' tables than linked though.

The reason we're focussing on PHPBB is that's the example you've shown - it may be a quirk of the particular installation of PHPBB that you're looking at, this certainly isn't a normal thing to find.

Can you use your tool with another database and see what results from that?

Also in terms of the database you have run your tool against - is that a custom installation that your organisation has performed?  My suspicion is that these unlinked tables that you can see have been added by custom modifications to the base PHPBB install, or are potentially unrelated tables that have been added to the database because it was convenient and available (e.g. the blog table).  Your best bet is to ask the person who supports that installation of the database.  In terms of your wider question - as mentioned above, its not a particularly normal pattern, but possibly a mix of addons and (mis)use of the database by other things would explain it.

Comment: please see my edit.  To answer your question "Can you provide the names of the unlinked tables you're looking at?"  Here are just a couple blog, privacy_type, php_bookmarks, phpbb_forums_track.  Those are just a few, there are about 50 of those "independent" tables.

Comment: that was run against a clean load of phpbb.  nos provided some information about the reverse engineering tools that could explain why the given result existed as it did.  Thanks for the help